# Drools 8.33 Equivalent to WorkingMemory.clearAgenda()

Tags: drools

I am porting an application that was built using Drools 2.5 to Java 11+.  This involves upgrading to a more recent version of Drools (8.33, the latest).

The application creates Decision Trees from .xls files.

In those older .xls files, the rightmost column on the RHS is called "Stop Processing" and the action is defined as drools.clearAgenda();

The first 10 rules contain nothing in the "Stop Processing" column but the 11th row contains the string "Stop Processing" - which invokes drools.clearAgenda() I presume.

The rules are sequential so I assume that this is telling the rules engine to just quit evaluating any more rules when it finishes with rule #11.

What is the equivalent to use in Drools 8.33 since clearAgenda() is no more?

No alternative that I can find.

Comment: My first version of Drools is Drools 5, so I really have no idea what Drools 2.5 even looks like -- but is there some reason you can't call `retract` and remove the key data from working memory?

Comment: I don't know what clearAgenda() does so I can't compare it with anything

Comment: I think what I am looking for is to replace drools.clearAgenda() with drools.halt();  And, in the java code, I call fireUntilHalt() instead of fileAllRules();  This should halt processing any more rules further down in the spread sheet.